# L2TP VPN is not working on Ubuntu 20.04. Same credential is working fine with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vpn, l2tp

L2TP VPN is not working on newly installed Ubunut 20.04 and 20.10. Credentials are correct and same is working with Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Even I format and reinstall ubuntu 20.04 without any other software, only required update installed, It is not working.

Comment: Viewing the output of `sudo journalctl --unit=NetworkManager` after a failed connection would be useful to determine what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The package network-manager-l2tp is required.

You may have to install it:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Well! I have already tried and installed it. but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this myself in Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04, and a simple one-liner solved all requirements necessary for my L2TP/IPsec setup to work properly:

```
sudo apt install --install-suggests network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

This installs all packages mentioned in the previous answers, too. Endpoint to connect to is a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter ERLite-3.

Comment: This worked for me on 21.10. `network-manager-l2tp` wasn't enough

Answer (score 1):

Check your log i suspect you may need to install these as well if the dependancy is not met:

```
 sudo apt install libstrongswan-standard-plugins libstrongswan-extra-plugins
```